# Question about Terminology in Mumford

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, terminology

Hello everyone,

I'm trying to look at Mumford's Paper, [The Pathologies of Modular Surfaces](http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/mumford/Papers/DigitizedAlgGeomPapers--ForNon-CommercialUse/61b--Path1.pdf).

On page 341, section II he says a certain surface can be constructed as the join of 3 graphs $E_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. What is the join of graphs?

Cheers!

Comment: Added [terminology] tag and fixed some typos.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_operations#Binary_operations does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **join** of two varieties $X,Y\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is 
$$ J(X,Y) = \overline{\bigcup_{\substack{x\in X,~y\in Y\\x\ne y}} \ell(x,y)}$$
where $\ell(x,y)$ denotes the projective line through $x$ and $y$. The join of $k$ varieties $X_1,\ldots,X_k\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is defined to be the closure of the union of the corresponding, projective $(k-1)$-folds, or by induction
$$J(X_1,\ldots,X_k) := J(X_1,J(X_2,\ldots,X_k))$$

This definition is from Joseph Landsberg's book *Tensors: Geometry and Applications*, page 118. The graph of a regular function is a projective variety, so this should be defined.

Answer (score 1):

A reference for the join of projective varieties, in Grothendieck's EGA style is

Altman, Allen B.; Kleiman, Steven L.: 
Joins of schemes, linear projections. Compositio Mathematica, **31** no. 3 (1975), pp. 309-343

You can dowload it [here](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CM_1975__31_3_309_0).